# Wix3.7 Custom Bootstrapper not showing WPF themes from a themes library

Tags: wix, wix3.6, bootstrapper, wix3.7

I've created a custom managed bootstrapper in WPF using Wix 3.7. I used an existing XAML themes library to create the bootstrapper UI. I added the  same themes library as a payload in the bootstrapper wxs file.

The problem is themes are getting applied during the design time but on running the bootstrapper's .exe file the themes are not getting applied.

Can some one tell me why it is happening?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to follow up with the implementation of the library to understand how the themes are loaded. Often, those types of libraries make assumptions that the files will be relative to the executable. Because the Burn engine is a native host those assumptions are incorrect. Instead, the library needs to load the themes relative to the current executing assembly.